# prettify doesn't highlight asp.net tags

Tags: asp.net, syntax-highlighting, prettify

I use google-code-prettify as my syntax highlighter, but i have a problem with asp.net tags, prettify doesn't recognize it, so code like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" 
                   runat="server" 
                   Text="partial postback" 
                   onclick="SubmitButton_Click" />

      <a href="#" id="clientClick"><span>jQuery</span></a>
     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

is ignored. i have noticed that stackoverflow is also using prettify. so i wonder how they do it?

Comment: Why do you believe SO uses prettify?

Comment: @Oded because they've said so

Comment: because i have looked into the page source.

Comment: @Oded, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33256/stackoverflows-code-color-coding-script-available

Answer (score 1):

Prettify author here.  If you have a code sample that demonstrates the problem, file a bug at http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/entry and I'll look into it.

Comment: Update: This was submitted here: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=166